# how to use custom user model for django-graphql-auth

Tags: django, authentication, graphql, django-graphql-jwt

I am using graphql in my project and want to generate token while registration. Even though django-graphql-auth has all the written mutation, it uses a different user model. But I want to use my custom user model. What should I do?
This is my user model

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
"""
Customized User Model
"""
email = models.EmailField(blank=True, null=True,
                          max_length=256, unique=True)
mobile_no = models.CharField(
    max_length=20, blank=True, null=True, unique=True)
verification_code = models.CharField(max_length=6)
code_valid_till = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

timezone = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True, null=True)
country = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='BD', choices=COUNTRIES)

pin_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
email_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)

modified_on = models.DateTimeField('date modified', auto_now=True)
created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

# For password reset
reset_verification_code = models.CharField(
    max_length=6, blank=True, null=True)
reset_code_valid_till = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
reset_request = models.BooleanField(default=False)
reset_valid_till = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = "User"

def __str__(self):
    if not self.is_anonymous:
        return "{} - {}".format(self.mobile_no, self.email)
    else:
        return "Anon"

@property
def get_full_name(self):
    return super().get_full_name()

def get_all_permissions(self, obj=None):
    return super().get_all_permissions(obj=obj)

def send_email(self, subject, message, to_email: list, from_email=None, **kwargs):
    send_mail_to_user(subject, message, from_email, to_email, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the author of the package. Now the documentation site has a custom user model in the quickstart, you can see it [here](https://django-graphql-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart/). <s>Currently, it's not documented how to use it with a custom user model, but it is already an open issue, you can see it [here](https://github.com/PedroBern/django-graphql-auth/issues/18)</s>. I will paste the same answer that is on the Github.

From [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#changing-to-a-custom-user-model-mid-project):

> Changing to a custom user model mid-project
>
> Changing AUTH_USER_MODEL after you’ve created database tables is
>   significantly more difficult since it affects foreign keys and
>   many-to-many relationships, for example.

So, make sure to create the custom user model when you start your project.

### Add the following to your custom user model

Following the [Django custom user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.CustomUser).

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    # ...
    USERNAME_FIELD = "<username_filed_name>" # e.g: "username", "email"
    EMAIL_FIELD = "<email_field_name>" # e.g: "email", "primary_email"
```

### Add your custom user model in the settings

See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model) for more info.

```py
# settings.py

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.CustomUser'
```

---

Please let me know if you have further questions :)

---

Edit: Add the `mobile_no` in the registration

Use the [REGISTER_MUTATION_FIELDS](https://django-graphql-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings/#register_mutation_fields) or [REGISTER_MUTATION_FIELDS_OPTIONAL](https://django-graphql-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings/#register_mutation_fields_optional).

```py
# settings.py


GRAPHQL_AUTH = {
    # ...

    REGISTER_MUTATION_FIELDS = [
        # ...
        'mobile_no'
    ]

    # or
    REGISTER_MUTATION_FIELDS_OPTIONAL = ['mobile_no']

    # You can set the graphene base scalars:
    REGISTER_MUTATION_FIELDS = {
        "email": "String",
        "username": "String",
        "mobile_no": "String",
    }
}
```

Comment: In my user model I wanted to take mobile_no as input as well as email while registering a new user. I tried to edit the code of your package but wasn't able to achieve the output. I am quite new at graphql, it would be great if you could help me out. I have added my user model in my question.

Comment: I don't have "email" field in my custom User Model can I not use graphql auth ?

Comment: set the username as the email field then.